# CSS property is red highlighted in github

Tags: github, sass

The `touch-action` property in a SCSS file is red highlighted in Github diff. Any reason why?

[image]

Here is the DOM for it:

[image]

Comment: The name of the CSS class that makes it red on github.com might be a good hint.

Comment: @amiuhle I have attached an image for the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, already searched for it myself - `.pl-li` doesn't seem to be useful information...

Comment: It isn't highlighted in CSS, so my best guess is that valid property names are outdated for the SCSS highlighter..?

Comment: Maybe? Sounds logical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: [Here is another example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X2iBD.png).

Comment: @cimmanon Whilst I agree, this is also a very techie question. Not only because most developers use GH but also from a technical perspective. Such as, rendering mechanism that GH might be using to colour the code might be open source and hence users outside of GH might also have some experience with this.

Comment: And what would you like those users to do with their experience?  If you would like to submit a bug report, I suggest you use the appropriate channel for that (hint: it's not here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github will highlight code like this if there is a syntax error. It's not 100% accurate, and it's not actually running your code.

Sometimes it will miss an error, other times it will highlight something that isn't an error. It is however still a handy feature.

I would imagine that as `touch-action` is not very well supported, the syntax checker that github use it not aware of it and thinks that it is not a valid property.

If the code works, I would just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to know, that's all! It is a new CSS property and is supported on many browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action But that makes sense.

Comment: I did. It's the green check mark on the left hand side.