# Dots in import statements becoming red - github compare

Tags: java, github

Why are all the dots in import statements shown as a red box?

It is happening only when I compare a particular branch. Every other branch's comparison works fine. Also, dots which are not in the import statements look normal.

The page I am on is `https://github.com/myCompany/my-app/compare/master...BR-1342` (mocked company and app name).

Here are some screenshots:-

[image]

[image]

**Update 1**

Here is the CSS of the dot:-
[image]

Also, I just noticed that it is showing this in all files that were changed in this branch, even if I select some other branch. And even in the "View file" pages, not only in the comparison pages.

Comment: Does this file have a `.java` suffix?

Comment: Yes @Mureinik. Actually I just noticed that it is showing this in all files that were changed in this branch, even if I select some other branch.

Comment: Can you check the CSS associated with the "red dot" element? (using the browser debug view)

Comment: @VonC updated the question with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30667675/6309), this seems to be the way for GitHub to mark a syntax error.
I have seen that for [xml files for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41341604/6309).

Somehow, parsing those java files is not correctly interpreted by GitHub in this case (but do check if those files actually compile).
It has been [reported as "not always reliable"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631734/6309).

Comment: Thanks @VonC. The code compiles fine. Import statements with dots are one of the most common things in the world; so even if this feature is not reliable, it's weird that it would show error here. If I don't find a better explanation, I'll go with your answer of "not always reliable" and ignore this highlighting.

Comment: As you mentioned, it turns out that this feature is not reliable. It looks fine now. I didn't change anything.